# Data binidng to an instance of class

Tags: c#, binding, collections

I am trying to bind an instance of a class to a ListBox in C#.

In my MainPage.xaml.cs

```
 protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            if (fan == null)
                fan = (Fanfou)e.Parameter;

            RefreshHomeTimeLine(fan.oauth_token, fan.oauth_token_secret);

        }

        private async void RefreshHomeTimeLine(string access, string access_secret)
        {
            string text=await fan.getFanfouApi("http://api.fanfou.com/statuses/home_timeline.json", access, access_secret);
            fanfouHomeTL = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FanfouHTL>(text);
        }
```

The fanfouHomeTL was good, containing a collection of statuses.

The declaration of that class is:

```
public class FanfouHTL
{
    private ObservableCollection<Status> statuses;

    public ObservableCollection<Status> Statuses
    {
        get
        {
            return statuses;
        }
        set
        {
            statuses = value;
        }
    }

}
```

Now I am trying to bind that instance to a `ListBox` (in a Grid) in `MainPage.xaml`. I have already created `ItemTemplate` for that `ListBox`. It seems that if I put the `DataContext` of the Grid to `FanfouHTL`（the class), nothing will be displayed in the `ListBox`; if I set the DC to `fanfouHomeTL` (the instance), `MainPage` will fail on `InitializeComponent`.

Any hint will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you share your xaml?
Assuming that the datacontext of the ListBox is an instance of FanfouHTL, you have to the set the ItemsSource as shown below
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Statuses}"/>

Comment: Can you give the exception type, message, and stack trace for "MainPage will fail"?

Answer (score 0):

Are you initialising the instance? Try making a public property instance of FanfouHTL, setting the data context of the listbox to your control and then binding to the property's collection, like so

```
public FanfouHTL Foobar {get;private set;}
//...snip...

public MyComponent(){
  Foobar = new FanfouHTL();
  InitialiseComponent();
}
```

Then, in your XAML

```
<UserControl x:Name="MyComponent" DataContext="{Binding RelativePath=Self}">
<!--(can't remember exact syntax here off the top of my head, but run with it)-->
    <ListBox ItemSource="{Binding Path=Foobar.Statuses}" />
</UserControl>
```

Comment: I have sorted it out myself. I can instanciate the class first and load the data. Then in OnNavigateTo event handler, assign: lbStatuses.ItemSource=htl.Statuses;